# php strtotime last day last month function produces 2 months ago

Tags: php, date

According to server:

```
 $ date
 Wed Mar  1 01:46:06 EST 2017
```

php.ini

```
 date.timezone = America/New_York
```

When I do this I get an odd result:

```
 $month = date('M',strtotime('last day last month'));
 $sel = "SELECT records where month='".$month."'";
 echo $sel;
```

The result is:

```
  SELECT records where month='Jan';
```

any ideas why not Feb?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using "next month", "last month", "+1 month",  "-1 month" or any combination of +/-X months.

It will give non-intuitive results on Jan 30th and 31st.

As described at : http://derickrethans.nl/obtaining-the-next-month-in-php.html

```
<?php
    $d = new DateTime( '2010-01-31' );
    $d->modify( 'next month' );
    echo $d->format( 'F' ), "\n";
?>
```

In the above, using "next month" on January 31 will output "March" even though you might want it to output "February".

("+1 month" will give the same result. "last month", "-1 month" are similarly affected, but the results would be seen at beginning of March.)

The way to get what people would generally be looking for when they say "next month" even on Jan 30 and Jan 31 is to use "first day of next month":

```
<?php
    $d = new DateTime( '2010-01-08' );
    $d->modify( 'first day of next month' );
    echo $d->format( 'F' ), "\n";
?>


<?php
    $d = new DateTime( '2010-01-08' );
    $d->modify( 'first day of +1 month' );
    echo $d->format( 'F' ), "\n";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try previous month instead of last month

```
  $month = date('M',strtotime('last day of previous month'));
```

Answer (score 0):

use code if you want last month

```
$month = date('M',strtotime('last month'));

$sel = "SELECT records where month='".$month."'";

echo $sel;
```

Result :

```
SELECT records where month='Feb'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// previous month
echo date("F t, Y", strtotime("last month"));

// two months ago
echo date("F t, Y", strtotime("last month -1 month"));
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.